# How to run the @app.route from other file

Tags: python, flask

I have app.py file as below

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "password"
```

My test.py is below

```
from app import app
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

I have done `export FLASK_APP=app` then `flask run`

My expected out in the browser `Hello world`

Disclaimer: creating the app.py and adding the below script works `perfect`. please don't answer like that.But need to upload app.py to another module but need to run app.py

```
`
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a folder let it be testing_flask and add both the app.py and test.py file inside the folder and also make an init file to form an module.
then app.py file look like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "password"

from testing_flask import test
```

test.py look like this:

```
from testing_flask.app import app

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

folder structure will be

```
- testing_flask
    |- __init__.py
    |- app.py
    |- test.py
```

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.